# Active Admin: Two pages for one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My `User` model can create either an `Employer` or a `Jobseeker`, depending on whether the boolean `Employer` attribute is true or not.

What I want to do is have separate pages for `Employer` and for `Jobseeker`, not just separate scopes. The pages will have completely different tables on.

Many thanks!

Comment: check out AA namespaces

Answer (score 9):

You can simply register your model twice but name it differently every time.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'Employer' do
  # ...
end

ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'Jobseeker' do
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a task add to 2 pages for 1 model too, but for the 1st page, I should display some fields, for 2nd - processing other fields for the same model.

In my case worked the next solution:

app/admin/user_processing.rb

```
  ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'User Processing' do
      menu label: 'User Processing', priority: 3
```

app/admin/user.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, as: 'User Data' do
  menu label: 'User Data', priority: 3
```

ps. I hope this solution helps you if you have the same case as me :)